# sample code not working in dart editor

Tags: dart

1. I download dart
2. I start the editor and choose the 'clock' sample
3. I attempt to run the sample
4. I get the message "Failed to load resource: the server responded
   with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)"

I've already tried these things:

I've followed these steps at different times with the same effect, so i don't think it was just a the pub server going down.

I tried running pub install but  I get the message "Pub install failed, [1] Resolving dependencies...Timed out trying to find package "browser" at https://pub.dartlang.org."

I tried running pub update but got a similar message "Pub update failed, [1] Resolving..... etc."

I have checked that my internet connection is working.

Comment: Maybe it was a temporary problem of the pub server. Try it again?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is proxy-related. [Issue 5454](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=5454) is marked as "Fixed", but there's still some discussion going on after it was marked as Fixed, so I'm not completely sure what the status is today.